# Javascript SDK: can i have another FB.api() calls inside FB.api()

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
// count total no. of groups created by me
function totalGroups(response) {
    FB.api('/me/groups', {fields:'owner'}, function(g_response) {
        for (i in g_response.data) {
            FB.api('/me', function(m_response) {
                var c = 0;
                if (g_response.data[i].owner.name == m_response.name) {
                    c++;
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('Total:' +c);
  });
}
```

hi, can i have another FB.api() calls inside FB.api() like i do on the above code because i can't get the value for **if (g_response.data[i].owner.name == m_response.name)**

Comment: You need to make a closure around `i`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: thanks @NULL, so if i put a closure it means i can have two FB.api() calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can embed a FB.api() call inside another Fb.api() call but the flow is guaranteed as the FB.api() calls are asynchronous.
One issue I found with your code is related to the `var c`.
First of all it's out of scope for `console.log('Total:' +c)` method and moreover you have declared it inside the loop which means it's value will be reset after each loop execution.

Try this:

```
// count total no. of groups created by me
function totalGroups(response) {
    var c = 0;
    FB.api('/me/groups', {fields:'owner'}, function(g_response) {
        for (i in g_response.data) {
            FB.api('/me', function(m_response) {               
                if (i.owner.name == m_response.name) {
                    c++;
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('Total:' +c);
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThePCWizard, your example still got an undefined `i.owner.name` but with a little experiment i got it working. thanks again.

Comment: glad, I could help, keep coding!!

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fix the problem, i know its ugly but it's the best i can do at the moment.

```
function totalGroups(response) {
    var c = 0;
    FB.api('/me', function(m_response) {
        FB.api('/me/groups', {fields:'owner'}, function(g_response) {
            for (i in g_response.data) {            
                if (g_response.data[i].owner) {
                    if (g_response.data[i].owner.name == m_response.name) {     
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log('Total: ' + c);
        });
    });
}
```